# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, ip-address, typeerror, hostname

I'm getting that strange TypeError when trying to get user's Hostname.

```
def getHostName(tfm, username):
    found = False
    for room in tfm.rooms.values():
            for playerCode, client in room.clients.items():
                    if client.username == username:
                            found = socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())[0]
                            break
    return found
```

This is what I used to get Hostname, and that's what it's erroring.

```
def getIPaddress(tfm, username):
    found = False
    for room in tfm.rooms.values():
            for playerCode, client in room.clients.items():
                    if client.username == username:
                            found = client.address[0]
                            break
    return found
```

This is what I used to get IP Address, successfully.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Wesley.py", line 544, in found_terminator
    tfm.parsePacket(packet, MDT, Size)
  File "Wesley.py", line 760, in parsePacket
    tfm.parseDataUTF(packet[2:struct.unpack('!h', packet[:2])[0]+2])
  File "Wesley.py", line 1063, in parseDataUTF
    Commands(tfm, values[0], values)
  File "/root/Server/Commands.py", line 2543, in ParseCommand
    hostname = tfm.server.getHostName(username)
  File "Wesley.py", line 5757, in getHostName
    found = socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())[0]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I used a command to specify the username.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full stacktrace, rather then just the last line?

Comment: Very weird. What gets printed to stdout if you add `print socket.gethostname()` in the line before the error occurs? What happens if you add in `print socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())` (without the `[0]` part)?

Comment: Wait, i'll do that when I finish eating.

Comment: ('vpslinux29', [], ['x.xxx.xx.xxx']) when hostname + name is typed.
    15:40:55 [COMMAND] Kikarz: 'hostname Eshkation'